# Webpack sass-loader no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: webpack

Sorry, I know there are countless other threads with the same issue, but I've tried all the solutions to no avail. I'm simply trying to compile scss files with webpack, but when I do I get the error:

ERROR in ./css/source/main.scss 3:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]

      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: This link may help you: https://developerhandbook.com/webpack/how-to-configure-scss-modules-for-webpack/

Comment: Have you tried removing the `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` line?

Comment: Yes I have, and from what I understand it’s required for what I want to do

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below format

```
{
    test: [/.css$|.scss$/],
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      "css-loader",
      "postcss-loader",
      "sass-loader"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: just a fun glob note, `test: /\.?(s)css$/i,` is sufficient